# What is llvm::NoneType and llvm::None used for?

Tags: c++, llvm

I am working on a huge code base of a C/C++ project based on LLVM. The code wasn't written by me, I am just reading and trying to understand what it means.

For example this code is the first time I encountered `llvm::None`

```cpp
CallInst *CI = this->CreateCall(Func, None, VALUE_NAME("localPtr"));
```

This is the definition of `CreateCall()` function.

```cpp
CallInst *CreateCall(Function *Callee, ArrayRef<Value *> Args,
                     const Twine &Name = "", MDNode *FPMathTag = nullptr) {
    return CreateCall(Callee->getFunctionType(), Callee, Args, Name, FPMathTag);
}
```

Apparently here the `llvm::None` is passed into the [`ArrayRef`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ArrayRef.html) `<Value *> Args`

According to LLVM reference ArrayRef

> Represent a constant reference to an array (0 or more elements consecutively in memory), i.e. a start pointer and a length. It allows various APIs to take consecutive elements easily and conveniently. This class does not own the underlying data, it is expected to be used in situations where the data resides in some other buffer, whose lifetime extends past that of the ArrayRef.

I am puzzled that `llvm::None` is passed into this parameter as an argument.

I could not find the documentation for `llvm::None` but I found the file in which it's declared.

```cpp
//===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//
//
//  This file provides None, an enumerator for use in implicit constructors
//  of various (usually templated) types to make such construction more
//  terse.
//
//===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//

#ifndef LLVM_ADT_NONE_H
#define LLVM_ADT_NONE_H

namespace llvm {
/// A simple null object to allow implicit construction of Optional<T>
/// and similar types without having to spell out the specialization's name.
// (constant value 1 in an attempt to workaround MSVC build issue... )
enum class NoneType { None = 1 };
const NoneType None = NoneType::None;
}

#endif
```

I do not understand what these comments in that file mean. So it it just the same as `1`? What is it for?

How can this be passed into the `ArrayRef`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of variables of type `Optional<Something>` in LLVM, for example to have an optional error, or an optional output file. `None` is a helper for `Optional` and similar, to let you construct such a thing simply and implicitly.

If you have a class with an optional file descriptor as a member field, then you can have a constructor that takes a file and one that doesn't, and `None` exists to simplify the second constructor, perhaps a copy constructor, etc.

Comment: Can you describe more about what is this `Optional`? I don't get it.

Comment: You're a C programmer at heart, rigt? C uses null pointers a great deal. So you have a pointer to something, or a null pointer. Optional does the same, except more pleasantly. Optional enables the compiler to enforce rules such as "all callers must check the return value" and often lets you omit checks, too.

Comment: Another C analogy is that `Optional<T>` is a tagged union of `T` and `None`

Comment: Thanks those analogies really helped.